# How can I use .htaccess to redirect if a particular GET variable contains non-numeric characters?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need a rule for .htaccess that will check a particular variable in the query string (which may or may not be present) and redirect to the same page, minus the query string, if the variable is not a five-digit number.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/mypage?myvar=12345       // This one is fine
https://www.example.com/mypage?myvar=987         // This one isn't
https://www.example.com/mypage?myvar=12-3a       // Neither is this one
https://www.example.com/mypage?othervar=whatever // Don't need to check this one
```

I know it can't be too complicated, but somehow I haven't hit on anything that works yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} myvar= [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)myvar=[0-9]{5}($|&) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) $1? [L,R=302,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This might not be the best way (comments  welcome!) but it's working as intended.